# How to do cumulative sum based on conditions in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below data and `final_column` is the exact output what I am trying to get. I am trying to do cumulative sum of `flag` and want to rest if `flag` is 0 then set value to 0 as below data

```
cola date       flag final_column
a   2021-10-01  0   0
a   2021-10-02  1   1
a   2021-10-03  1   2
a   2021-10-04  0   0
a   2021-10-05  0   0
a   2021-10-06  0   0
a   2021-10-07  1   1
a   2021-10-08  1   2
a   2021-10-09  1   3
a   2021-10-10  0   0
b   2021-10-01  0   0
b   2021-10-02  1   1
b   2021-10-03  1   2
b   2021-10-04  0   0
b   2021-10-05  0   0
b   2021-10-06  1   1
b   2021-10-07  1   2
b   2021-10-08  1   3
b   2021-10-09  1   4
b   2021-10-10  0   0
```

I have tried like

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("final_column",expr("sum(flag) over(partition by cola order date asc)"))
```

I have tried to add condition like `case when flag = 0 then 0 else 1 end` inside sum function but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a column `group` using conditional sum on `flag`, then using `row_number` with a Window partitioned by `cola` and `group` gives the result you want:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val result = df.withColumn(
    "group",
    sum(when(col("flag") === 0, 1).otherwise(0)).over(Window.partitionBy("cola").orderBy("date"))
).withColumn(
    "final_column",
    row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("cola", "group").orderBy("date")) - 1
).drop("group")

result.show

//+----+-----+----+------------+
//|cola| date|flag|final_column|
//+----+-----+----+------------+
//|   b|44201|   0|           0|
//|   b|44202|   1|           1|
//|   b|44203|   1|           2|
//|   b|44204|   0|           0|
//|   b|44205|   0|           0|
//|   b|44206|   1|           1|
//|   b|44207|   1|           2|
//|   b|44208|   1|           3|
//|   b|44209|   1|           4|
//|   b|44210|   0|           0|
//|   a|44201|   0|           0|
//|   a|44202|   1|           1|
//|   a|44203|   1|           2|
//|   a|44204|   0|           0|
//|   a|44205|   0|           0|
//|   a|44206|   0|           0|
//|   a|44207|   1|           1|
//|   a|44208|   1|           2|
//|   a|44209|   1|           3|
//|   a|44210|   0|           0|
//+----+-----+----+------------+
```

`row_number() - 1` in this case is just equivalent to `sum(col("flag"))` as flag values are always 0 or 1. So the above `final_column` can also be written as:

```scala
.withColumn(
    "final_column",
    sum(col("flag")).over(Window.partitionBy("cola", "group").orderBy("date"))
)
```